# How do I ignore "table" property in a button within a row of that table?

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4, html-table

I'm using bootstrap and have a table with property "table" to make a light background to the data displayed from a database. It looks well, except when I'm adding a button to each row, which is supposed to help me edit data in that row. The button itself gets white and almost invisible, but if I remover "table" property the data is displayed incorrectly.

How can I ignore "table"-property in button element only? Setting color of button in .btn-css didn't help.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<table class="table cons-table table-striped border">
        <thead>
           //Some code
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            //Some code
            //Button not displaying correctly
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Change</button>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

And here comes CSS-code. Color changes have no effect:

```
.btn {
    background-color: solid;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: 24a0ed;
}
```

Comment: This in invalid HTML

Comment: I'm using Vue-framework.

Comment: It's still invalid HTML. Vue doesn't make you write invalid HTML AFAIK.

Comment: It compiles, how can it be invalid?

Comment: Put it in an HTML validator. Browser will never throw errors for invalid HTML, but it can have unexpected side effects

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using !important?

```
.btn-primary {
  background-color: 24a0ed !important;
}
```

Comment: @Silvervarg can you create a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help, as the code is taking in an external database to display, but in case you would like to see the whole code structure of the file here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/SilverVarg/fcpwy53o/9/